# Given that $\tan 2x+\tan x=0$, show that $\tan x=0$

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $\tan 2x+\tan x=0$, show that $\tan x=0$

Using the Trigonometric Addition Formulae,

\begin{align}
\tan 2x & = \frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan ^2 x} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan ^2 x}+\tan x & = 0 \\ 
\ 2\tan x+\tan x(1-\tan ^2 x) & = 0 \\
2+1-\tan ^2 x & = 0 \\ 
\tan ^2 x & = 3
\end{align}

This is as far as I can get, and when I look at the Mark Scheme no other Trignometric Identities have been used. Thanks

Comment: You have made a mistake between the third and the fourth equality... the bracket expansion is incorrect. One you correct that you can solve the problem, via an intuitive substitution

Comment: @b00n heT I divided both sides by $\tan x$

Comment: How can you if it is zero?

Comment: There is your error. Recall that $xf(x)=0 \iff x=0 \lor f(x)=0$. It is a very common mistake to divide out the $x$, and thus to lose a trivial, but important, solution

Comment: And you have got the solution correct.. $tan(x)$ is **either** **0** or $\pm \sqrt 3$

Comment: Having got as far as $\tan x(3-\tan^2x)=0$ you can conclude that either $\tan x=0$ or $\tan x=\pm\sqrt3$.

Comment: @almagest Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. As written, the assertion is not correct since

> $$
> \tan\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)+\tan\left(\frac{\pi}3\right)=0
> $$ but $$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}3\right)=\sqrt{3}\color{red}{\neq}0.$$

There is a mistake in your reasoning, starting as you did you obtain
$$
 \left(\frac{2\color{blue}{\tan x}}{1-\tan ^2 x}+\color{blue}{\tan x}\right)=0
$$ which one may rewrite as
$$
\color{blue}{\tan x} \times\left(\frac{2}{1-\tan ^2 x}+1\right)=0
$$ or
$$
\tan x \times\left(\frac{\color{red}{3-\tan^2 x}}{1-\tan ^2 x}\right)=0
$$ giving

> $$
> \tan x=0 \quad \text{or}\quad\color{red}{\tan^2 x=3}.
> $$

that is explicitly

$$
x=\pm k\pi \quad \text{or}\quad x=\pm \dfrac{\pi}3\pm k\pi
$$ $k=0,1,2,\ldots$.

Comment: How did you get to $\tan x \times\left(\frac{2}{1-\tan ^2 x}+1\right)=0$

Comment: @ThomasWinkworth By factoring $\frac{2\color{red}{\tan x}}{1-\tan ^2 x}+\color{red}{\tan x}=0$. Do you see it?

Comment: @ThomasWinkworth bro don't worry about that,you are on right track,but you made mistake on divison by 0

Comment: I think it is confusing to say the assertion is not correct. It is partly correct, since $\tan(x)=0$ might be a solution to the equation. However, it might not be as shown by your example. So the assertion to prove would be the assertion as stated at the end of your answer. Nicely worked out btw..

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading correctly, but if the assertion is $\tan(2x)+\tan x=0 \implies \tan x=0$ (which is the way I've understood it). Then it is not correct. No?

Comment: Formally this is a good use of the term correct. Im however not saying your use is not good, but it might be confusing.. For didactical reasons you might want to be more explicit in your point.

Comment: @TimHuijgens The OP says "Given that $\tan 2x+\tan x=0$, show that $\tan x=0$". This is not correct since given that $\tan (2\pi/3)+\tan(\pi/3)=0$, we don't have $\tan (\pi/3)=0$.

Comment: I get it, basically $\tan x(3-\tan^2x)=0$

Comment: @ThomasWinkworth Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the following conditions are equivalent:
\begin{align*}
\tan x + \tan y &= 0\\
\tan x &= -\tan y\\
\tan x &= \tan(-y)\\
x &= -y + k\pi\\
x+y&= k\pi
\end{align*}
If we use $y=2x$ we get
\begin{align*}
3x &= k\pi\\
 x &= k\frac\pi3
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

In line 4 you divided both side with $\tan x$ assuming that $\tan x\neq0$

($1$) So, if $\tan x\neq0$, you are on right track. $x=60^\circ$

($2$) But, if $\tan x=0$, you didn't consider this one. So, $\tan x=0\implies x=0^\circ$

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan x+\tan2x=\dfrac{\sin(x+2x)}{\cos x\cos2x}$$

So, we need $\sin3x=0\implies3x=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

By the double angle formula we get $$\tan(2x)+\tan(x)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}+\tan(x)=\frac{3-\tan^2(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}\tan(x),$$ so that $\tan(x)=0$ is certainly a solution.

But $\tan(x)=\pm\sqrt3$ as well, so that the initial claim is false.